# Indexing issue with a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, do-while

I have a `for` loop where I'm using the *slide* operator as I'm working with unsigned types. Essentially it boils down to

```
for (std::size_t i = 6; i --> 0;){
    cout << i;
}
```

But it outputs the numbers from 5 to 0 inclusive and omits 6. Why?

Thank you very much for looking at this. I'm quite stuck.

Comment: I'm at a loss here. I *should* upvote this since the question is well-written with a nice example. But the concepts behind it are awful. Why would someone write code like this?

Comment: "_Slide_" operator?? You are just doing this `(i--)  >  0;`

Comment: @Bathsheba, the question opens the door for discussion about the awfulness of its topic. Since it's also well written, I'd say it's a very good question.

Comment: Actually, this is precisely what the "slide operator" should do: iterate over the indices in the interval `[0, count[`, where zero is assumed to be included while `count` is excluded. Just like how you index an array in C. Thus, with a vector `array`, the following is correct: `for(size_t i = array.size(); i --> 0; ) {...}`, or even shorter: `for(size_t i = array.size(); i--; ) {...}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a touchstone for

1. The fact that this so-called "operator" should be used with caution, if at all.
2. Changing the state of variables within the conditional check of a `for` loop ought to be done with extreme caution, if at all.

The largest output is 5 simply because `i` is decremented as a result of the conditional test which also decrements `i`. The conditional check is ran before program control enters the `for` loop body.

You really ought to rewrite the loop. **Don't** set the initial value of `i` to 7 as that's a dirty hack. Although `-->` is often used with `while` (and to emphasise, it's unlikely to win you many friends in your programming review), I've never seen it used with a `for` loop before.

Answer (score 4):

`-->` is not a *slide* operator.

It is understood by the compiler as two different operators `--` and `>`.

So your code look like this to the compiler:

```
for (std::size_t i = 6; (i--) > 0;){
    cout << i;
}
```

Since the loop condition is checked before entering the loop's body `i` is decreased before the first execution of the loop's body, hence the produced sequence of numbers is 5 4 3 2 1 0.

For more details see this Stack Overflow question: [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

After evaluating this condition in the for statement

```
i --> 0
```

i will be equal to `5`. So the first iteration of the loop outputs

`5`

To achieve the effect you want rewrite the loop the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    size_t i = 6;

    do
    {
        std::cout << i;
    } while ( i-- > 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
6543210
```

Another way is the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    for ( size_t i = 6; std::cout << i && i != 0; i-- )
    {
        //
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you could write the loop like this

```
const size_t N = 6;

for ( size_t i = N + 1; i-- > 0; )
//              ^^^^^^^    
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

However in general this approach does not work when the initial value of i is equal to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` Because if to add 1 to this value you will get 0.

A general approach using a for loop can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 6;

    for ( size_t i = N, j = N; j != 0; j = i-- )
    {
        std::cout << i;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
6543210
```